# SQL server - schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We can see schema for all tables and views by:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

Can we view schema for stored procedures or functions through tsql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx), like [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx):

> Returns one row for each stored
>   procedure and function that can be
>   accessed by the current user in the
>   current database

Comment: Thanks-
Related to this:
If a SQL agent job is running a stored procedure with a schema say 'xschema' and it runs other stored procedures with dbo schema. Under what circumstances, this main stored procedure woint find one of the child procedures? ( this is enough information?)

thanks in advance

Comment: If a SQL Agent job is running dbo.usp_foo and this in turn invokes myschema.usp_foo and fails with an error `Cannot find the object myschema.usp_foo because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.` the the problem is most likely related to permissions, the account under which the job step is run doesn't have execute permission on `myschema.usp_foo`.